# How can I run Android unit tests while not simultaneously starting the application?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

When I run unit tests by Android Studio, the testrunner executes the test methods of the test case (which extends AndroidTestCase) as expected. However, the actual application (which extends Application) is started, too. Naturally this interferes with the unit tests, since both use the same classes and hardware resources. I have no idea why Android Studio (or any other module) starts the application?

I'm running the unit test e.g. by using the context menu of Android Studio (v 1.3.2), selecting the test case file/class and the selecting 'run' (ctrl+shift+f10), or using the run menu from the menu bar. The application and/or the unit tests run on a real device (HTC Nexus 9 Android 5.1.1 API 22) connected via USB. I can't use the emulator, since it does not provide bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version of Android Studio you are using, there are 2 types of tests,

- "Unit Tests" and
- "Android Instrumentation Tests"

which can be selected in the tab called "Build variants".

[image]

Android Instrumentation Tests launch the Application, while Unit Tests not. You can search the net of how to configure each and when to use the one over the other.

Some links to get you started:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html

Comment: Thanks for this good starting point. I find the 2nd link most useful. So now I understand that I need instrumented tests for testing Java classes which use the Android API, using the AndroidJUnitRunner.

Comment: One thing that you might need to pay attention is the following warning from the second link:
Warning The creation of the Java folder might add the new test directory as source file to your build.gradle file. If you have the following entry in your app/build.gradle file you need to REMOVE it. test should NOT be treated as normale source folder.
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java/'] } } 

If I didn't do this Unit Tests shown up in Instumentation tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually 2 types of tests in Android Studio, the instrumentation test and the unit test. Running an instrumentation test will launch your application for sure since it executes and Android component running in a lifecycle determined by the system. A unit test will not launch your application, because its execute methods not related to any Android API. So in your case it depends on what are you testing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'm running unit tests: I implemented a class 'MyTestCase' extending AndroidTestCase adding test... methods. Now I right-click 'MyTestCase' class and select run. The testrunner starts the 1st test...method of 'MyTestCase'. Ok. But before the Application is started, which is in a different package of course. It isn't even in the packages being tested by 'MyTestCase'. So there is not link from the test case to the application.

Comment: @user2261015 if it's a unit test, and you don't need an application context in your test functions, there's no need for you test class to extend anything.